# Summing elements in a 2D list, and then dividing that number, and then converting that number to a character

Tags: haskell

I need to sum the elements from a 2D list of three- tuples of Ints
E.g[(10,50,50),(60,70,90),(100,100,20)],](50,60,100),(60,70,90),(60,40,30)]

and divide it by 3 and then 255.

right now I have this

```
PatternMatch:: [Char] -> Bool -> (Int, Int, Int)-> Char
PatternMatch _ _[] = []
PatternMatch ((a,b,c):xs) = (((a + b + c) / 3) / 255) : (PatternMatch xs)
```

But this returns it as an integer, but I need a char. For that I need a helper function, but idk how to go about this. Please help!

Comment: Did you do any research before asking this question? [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Int+-%3E+Char) helps in this kind of situation.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Be sure to take the
[tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and visit the [help
center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Could you please elaborate, why did you choose this particular type signature for `PatternMatch`? What `[Char]` and `Bool` arguments are supposed to do? Also, you say that you want to perform an operation on a _list_ of triples, but put a plain triple in the signature. You may want to align the description of what you're trying to do with what you've actually tried, or maybe the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

Hoogle and google can easily help you with this question. You are just looking for a function of type `Int -> String` (char would be restricted to only one digit; also watch out for decimal values). You'll find that the well-known function `Show` does what you need.
Also, dividing by 3 and 255 makes your code look weird, just divide by 765 at once.
Finally, there's no need for pattern matching for a function like this, you can use the higher order function `map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]` and either write your own helper function or use a lambda function:

```
patternMatch  :: [(Int,Int,Int)] -> String
patternMatch = concat . map (show . (\(x,y,z) -> (x+y+z) `div` 765))
```

P.S.: If you are sure you'll only get integers 0..9, then you can use an even simpler list comprehension:

```
patternMatch tups = [head . show $ (x+y+z) `div` 765 |(x,y,z) <- tups]
```

Comment: The first version is not correct: it should be [(Int, Int, Int)], and you should then map a composition of `show` and the lambda, right now you're composing the lambda with `map show`. But even with this it will not work, since you can't use `/` with `Int`s, you'd need `div` (or `quot`), like you did in the comprehension.

Comment: @Michail you're absolutely right I forgot the brackets in the type declaration and around the function - EDITED now. However I can still do a floating point division because the compiler will just convert it to a float type and return a float, because it wasn't clear what the OP wanted and that's what he used in its version.

Comment: Haskell doesn't have implicit type conversions. `/` requires its arguments to be of the same type and be `Fractional`, which `Int` isn't. The function will typecheck if you omit the signature, because the compiler will infer `Fractional a => [(a, a, a)] -> String` for it. It will accept a list with some integer _literals_ inside, but they will not be `Int`s, they will actually be floats or doubles. If you try to feed explicitly annotated `Int`s into it, the program will be rejected.

Comment: oops, my bad, also `Show a` for the inferred type.

Comment: @Michail you're actually quite right, my apologies. I only checked in the GHCi without giving it the type declaration. Edited my answer again